# Removing the line from a graph label in pgf

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I've produced a graph with the following code:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
    trig format plots=rad,
    axis lines = middle,
    enlargelimits,
    clip=false,
    ticks=none
    ]
    \addplot[domain=0:2*pi,samples=100,brown] {sin(x)} node [pos=0.25,pin={90:$\mathbf{F}_{bs}$},inner sep=0pt] {};
    \addplot[domain=0:2*pi,samples=100,black] {sin(x-(2*pi)/3)} node [pos=0.57,pin={90:$\mathbf{F}_{cs}$},inner sep=0pt] {};
    \addplot[domain=0:2*pi,samples=100,gray] {sin(x+(2*pi)/3)} node [pos=0.925,pin={90:$\mathbf{F}_{as}$},inner sep=0pt] {};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

This produces the following:

[image]

I'd like to remove the line that connects the plot to the label. Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Option `pin` can be replaced by `label`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
    trig format plots=rad,
    axis lines = middle,
    enlargelimits,
    clip=false,
    ticks=none
    ]
    \addplot[domain=0:2*pi,samples=100,brown] {sin(x)} node
    [pos=0.25,label={90:$\mathbf{F}_{bs}$},inner sep=0pt] {};
    \addplot[domain=0:2*pi,samples=100,black] {sin(x-(2*pi)/3)} node
    [pos=0.57,label={90:$\mathbf{F}_{cs}$},inner sep=0pt] {};
    \addplot[domain=0:2*pi,samples=100,gray] {sin(x+(2*pi)/3)} node
    [pos=0.925,label={90:$\mathbf{F}_{as}$},inner sep=0pt] {};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]